# vertical scrolling via scrollTo is jittery on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755887/window-scrollto-causes-flickering-on-mobile-devices) but it wasn't answered.

I have a object on a webpage that I want you to be able to drag and scroll the page.  Reason behind this is that I set it up to be a swipe'able window but on some mobile devices the window takes up most of the screen.  So in addition to horizontal "swiping" I want you to be able to vertically scroll the page as well.

This works great on a PC with a mouse.  Everything is smooth and as expected.  However, once you go to a mobile device (I have tried on Safari on an iPhone and the native browser on an Android 4 and both have the same issue) vertical scrolling is very "jittery".

At first I thought that it had to do with the fact that after you scroll the page, the next touchmove / MSPointerMove event will return a Ycord that different even though your finger might not have moved (due to the scrolling).  But trying to accomidate for this didn't help.

Anyway, a demo of the whole thing can be found at http://www.leecolpi.com/NEW/m/
The full javascript can be found at http://www.leecolpi.com/NEW/m/JAVASCRIPT/slide_window.js

The relivant javascript is (might be easier to read via the link above):

```
function mouseMoveTrigger(evt)
{
  if (!isDragging) return;

  if (!touchEvents && !pointerEvents)
    if (window.event) evt=window.event;

  if (evt.preventDefault)
    evt.preventDefault();
  else
    evt.returnValue = false;

  var newX;
  var newY;
  if (touchEvents)
  {
    newX = offsetX - evt.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    offsetX = evt.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    newY = offsetY - evt.changedTouches[0].pageY;
    offsetY = evt.changedTouches[0].pageY;
  }
  else
  {
    newX = offsetX - evt.clientX;
    offsetX = evt.clientX;
    newY = offsetY - evt.clientY;
    offsetY = evt.clientY;
  }

  var thingsToSlide = document.getElementById("pictureFrame").getElementsByTagName("li");
  newX = parseInt(thingsToSlide[0].style.right.replace(/px/g,'')) + newX;

  if (newX < 0)
    newX = 0;
  if (newX > ((thingsToSlide[0].offsetWidth * (thingsToSlide.length - 1))) + 30)
    newX = (thingsToSlide[0].offsetWidth * (thingsToSlide.length - 1)) + 30;

  window.scrollBy(0, newY);

  for (var i=0; i<thingsToSlide.length; i++)
    thingsToSlide[i].style.right = newX + "px";

  return false;
}
```

As you can see, all I am doing is a scrollBy of the difference of the Yvalue for the current and previous "move" events.  Again, this works like a champ on a computer which is exactly where I don't care if it works or not.  Only problem is every mobile device I have tried it on.

I am using preventDefault() (or setting the return value = false if I can't do that), but could I be triggering another event and not knowing it?  I tried with my init to only listen for certian events.  Here is my init function (might be easier to read via the link above):

```
function initSlider()
{
  var pageBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var thingsToSlide = document.getElementById("pictureFrame");
  if (thingsToSlide)
  {
    var thingsToSlideList = document.getElementById("pictureFrame").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i<thingsToSlideList.length; i++)
      thingsToSlideList[i].style.right = "0px";

    if (touchEvents)
    {
      thingsToSlide.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart, false);
    }
    else if (pointerEvents)
    {
      thingsToSlide.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onTouchStart, false);
    }
    else
    {
      thingsToSlide.ondrag=function() { return false; };
      thingsToSlide.onselectstart=function() { return false; };
      thingsToSlide.onmousedown=function(event) { mouseDownTrigger(this,event); };
    }

    if (touchEvents)
    {
      pageBody.addEventListener("touchmove", mouseMoveTrigger, false);
      pageBody.addEventListener("touchend", mouseUpTrigger, false);
      pageBody.addEventListener("touchcancle", mouseUpTrigger, false);
    }
    else if (pointerEvents)
    {
      pageBody.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", mouseMoveTrigger, false);
      pageBody.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", mouseUpTrigger, false);
      pageBody.addEventListener("MSPointerCancel", mouseUpTrigger, false);
    }
    else
    {
      document.onmousemove = mouseMoveTrigger;
      document.onmouseup = mouseUpTrigger;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance